# How to get and send LinkedIn messages via API?

Tags: linkedin-api

How do I get and send LinkedIn messages via the current API? curl examples would be great, but at this point I'd be jazzed to a have a link to an OpenAPI spec or some other current and complete documentation.

Comment: an example of curl is here https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/guide/v2/communications/messages#

Comment: Saw that, but its for downloading an attachment and not for sending/getting messages (one would think the docs would be in a similar space)